# window.unbeforeunload not working to trigger function in external .js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

In an webpage I have I want to end my connection to my data transfer service if a user is to close the page. The code for disconnection is there, and works perfectly fine on button click, but when I try to use onbeforeunload to trigger the function it doesn't work. I've gotten onbeforeunload to display text before the page closes, but not to trigger my function. My attempted disconnect code in the header simply reads as follows:

```
<script>

    window.onbeforeunload = disconnect();
// doesnt like the idea of working  
</script>
```

The disconnect function exists in an external .js file that is referenced in the html file. I cannot understand why it will not trigger this function before closing the document. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
window.onbeforeunload = disconnect;
```

In order to reference a function to another variable/property you have to assign the function body itself, that you can access by calling only the function name, e.g. `disconnect`(type it on your console and you will have the function body).

When you try to assign the function with `()` you are executing it, and assigning its return value at the moment of the assign, so the event will try to evaluate its return value at the moment it will be triggered and not the function itself.

I hope this is clear.

Answer (score 1):

In your example you are executing disconnect when you assign the eventhandler.

It should be:

```
window.onbeforeunload = disconnect;
```

Comment: Anything different from my answer?